# Advanced Custom Fields – Multiple Select Output

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using Advanced Custom Fields and got multiple select field going where the user back end selects apple, oranges, pears etc for example.

I am trying to get the front end to show images of each one if selected. So far I have the following;

```
$labels = array();
  $field = get_field_object('fruit');
  $values = get_field('fruit');
  foreach ($values as $value) {
  $labels[] = $field['choices'][ $value ];}

  echo implode(', ', $labels);
```

Can anyone help please so it shows each one separately and as an image?